# Python - break out into first while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Alright, I have a while loop based on an input here -

```
username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
while(len(username) > 0):
    counter = 0
    for c in username:
        if(c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'u' or c == 'o'):
            counter+=1
    ending = 'vowels' if counter > 1 else 'vowel'
    print(f"word has {counter} {ending}!")
    break
```

After printing number of vowels I need to break out and prompt for a new username. But break results in the program exiting, and continue infinitely repeats the last print.

How can I break out back to the first input?

Comment: You don’t need the parentheses around the if statement and loop, nor do you need to call `str()` on the result of `output()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the first input in the loop:

```
username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
while(len(username) > 0):
    counter = 0
    for c in username:
        if(c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'u' or c == 'o'):
            counter+=1
    ending = 'vowels' if counter > 1 else 'vowel'
    print(f"word has {counter} {ending}!")
    username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
```

The program will end when you give no input (press enter directly)

Comment: Is `str(input(...))` to convert the input into a string? According to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `input` "reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat getting usernames, then that statement has to be within a loop.  One standard way is to repeat that code at the bottom of your loop.

```
username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
while(len(username) > 0):
    counter = 0
    for c in username:
        if(c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'u' or c == 'o'):
            counter+=1
    ending = 'vowels' if counter > 1 else 'vowel'
    print(f"word has {counter} {ending}!")
    # Get another username
    username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get another user input **inside the loop**:

```py
username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
while(len(username) > 0):
    counter = 0
    for c in username:
        if(c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'u' or c == 'o'):
            counter+=1
    ending = 'vowels' if counter > 1 else 'vowel'
    print(f"word has {counter} {ending}!")
    username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower() # Here!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `if` and `break` inside loop:

```
while True:
    username = str(input('whats your favorite word? (enter to quit)')).strip().lower()
    if not username:  # check if username is an empty string
        break
    # calculations and print are here
```